Should software developer put personal projects on resume to cover most recent extended employment gap?
I am a software developer, but have been out of work for more than 2 years. For several months now, I've been looking for a job, but rather unsuccessfully - looks like my resume is simply being ignored because of that glaring gap.
I also started applying for QA positions, but the result is the same (I'm planning to post a separate question on this).
Earlier in the year, I became a contributor to a project on github, and also started doing there a couple projects on my own. 
Nothing really fancy (i.e. not the enterprise level development I normally did as part of my actual work experience); just to keep myself in shape and learn a few things in the process.
Recently, I started adding those projects on my resume to somehow cover the gap. One of the projects has a front end with webservices as a backend, so I deployed it on the cloud to show a working product (in case if my resume somehow ends up on a desk of somebody technical and they decide to hit the URL and click around). 
I've done a couple of submissions using this version of my resume, but result is the same radio silence.
So I am not sure if I am making matter worse by adding those projects on my resume, or it does not really matter in my situation?

@gnat, thank you. Although there is useful info in that post, it seems to me that it might not be 100% relevant to my situation:
the OP was out of work for just 5 months and sounds like it was his choice to quit his job to work on his projects.
I've had a few gaps like this (i.e. a few months or even longer) in my career, and none of them caused me any grief in finding another job. I would not even bother to explain them on my resume or cover letter.
Also, he started working on his projects from day 1, whereas in my case it was not until almost 2 years past.

@Joe Strazzere, after my last contract was over, initially I was just taking a break for a few months. And then I had to deal with some urgent family matters, including caring for a sick family member

Two years is a long time, I once took a hiatus from software development and actually spent the whole time coding, I went back because I was too busy coding and not making an alternative income as planned.  One solution in your situation is to think of a commercial product you can get online quickly, register the business and say that you are currently employed there and look for work while being "currently employed" so you can't use them as a reference
